# ¿Por qué no aparecen mis estilos e imágenes?

Tags: html, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Estoy realizando una página de registro con bootstrap, html y thymeleaf. Cuando abro el localhost este solo me trae los campos pero nada de los estilos o imágenes con las que originalmente lo hice. Intenté ver algunos tutoriales pero no di con el problema con el tutorial que estuve viendo.

Creo que el problema debería estar en el form pero la verdad no estoy seguro si sea solo eso o estoy usando mal las etiquetas de thymeleaf.

Estas son unas partes del código donde podría estar el problema:

```
<head th:fragment="head">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title th:text="${Registrate}"></title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="\src\main\resources\static\img\Icono.jpg">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/main/resources/static/css/Registro.css">
</head>

<body class="bg-dark">
  <header>
    <nav id="header" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand text-Intro" href="#">
          <img src="\src\main\resources\static\img\Icono.jpg">PeliReview
        </a>
```

Se ve así cuando la abro por spring pero por el live server abre

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si no aparecen es porque las rutas que pones estan mal. Puede ser que te hayas equivocado de ruta o que usar la contrabarra \ en lugar de la barra inclinada normal `/` en las rutas te esté afectando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El path `/src/main/resources/` no tiene sentido una vez que has desplegado la aplicación. Ese path sólo tiene sentido dentro del proyecto, para facilitar la organización de los ficheros:

```
/  -> Raíz, donde está el fichero de Maven o Gradle, el readme y, si existen, los directorios de los módulos hijos.
* -src -> Todo el código y los recursos, pero en subdirectorios
  *- main -> Código y recursos que se ejecutan en producción (en subdirectorios)
    *- java -> Código Java
    *- resources -> Ficheros de configuración, assets...
      *-/static -> Ficheros que deben estar fuera del JAR, directamente disponibles para peticiones HTTP
  *- test-> Código y recursos para los tests
    *- java -> Código Java de los tests
    *- resources -> Ficheros de configuración para tests y recursos necesarios
```

Pero dentro del JAR/WAR generado, todo lo que haya en `/src/main/java` y `/src/main/resources` se copia a la raíz del archivo, con la excepción de `/src/main/resources/static` que se despliega fuera del archivo para estar accesible desde el cliente.

Si tienes algo en `/src/main/resources/static`, pasa a ser simplemente `/`

Comment: uffff hermano eres god muchas gracias ya pude solucionarlo

Comment: Si esta respuesta te solucionó el problema, puedes marcarla como "aceptada" para dejar la pregunta como respondida :)